# Windows batch file : How to redirect console logs of a background process to 'NUL'

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, background-process

I have created a batch file which calls a java process in background. All I want is to redirect the logs of the java process to a 'NUL' output so that the background terminal **does not** contain any output.

Contents of my batch file:

```
@echo off
START /MIN java -jar ./myapp.jar >null 2>&1
```

However when I run the batch, I minimized windows terminal opens up which still displays all the logs.

I require to disable this logging, without changing the app.jar

Comment: Use `javaw` instead of `java`

Comment: try `START /B` instead of `/MIN`

Comment: You should redirect to `nul` (the Windows _null_ device) rather than `null` (a file called `null.`);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to ignore any console input and output, execute your Java program on a Windows platform and need to prevent the opening of a console window, then use the `javaw` executable instead of `java`.

Answer (score 0):

[dotvav's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34063811/886887) is best in your scenario, but for the record the proximate problem with your batch script as posted is that the redirection applies to the START command, not to the `java` command.

A corrected version would look something like this:

```
START /MIN cmd /c "java -jar ./myapp.jar >NUL 2>&1"
```